# Custom logging for notice warnings

Tags: magento-1.9, log, error-log, logging

I am using magento 1.9.1.0. I had continously trouble with modules which throw notice warnings which in turn broke some functionality. So I've managed to ignore Notice Warnings by putting `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` in index.php, get.php and api.php.

Before that I managed to handle these errors with my own handler in index.php

```
set_error_handler('noticeErrorHandler', E_NOTICE | E_STRICT) ;

function noticeErrorHandler($code, $err_msg, $err_file, $err_line, array $err_context) {
  $error = $log = null;
  switch ($code) {
    case E_NOTICE:
    case E_USER_NOTICE:
      $error = 'Notice';
      break;
    case E_STRICT:
      $error = 'Strict';
      break;
  }

  Mage::Log($error . ": " . $err_msg . " in " . $err_file . " on line " . $err_line, null, "notices.log");
}
```

But Mage::Log is not working before Mage::run and it is not really a nice solution to put this in index.php.

My question is: is there a nice solution to prevent Magento from raising errors for notice warnings and put them in an own notices.log file for every site request, like api requests too?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to add `true` as 4th parameter of `Mage::log()` method

Answer (score 0):

By default, Magento does not log messages about errors and exceptions;

So if something bad happens, you don't even know.

To turn on the logging, you can navigate to

**System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings**

and set the **«Enabled» option to «Yes»**

Also var and var/log folder permission need to be **0777**